# Combine columns to remove NaN in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I would like to combine multiple columns into one column to remove the NaN in `Julia`. Here is some reproducible data:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(
    V1 = [3,NaN,1,NaN,NaN],
    V2 = [NaN,4,NaN,NaN,NaN],
    V3 = [NaN,NaN,NaN,7,NaN]
)
```

Output:

```
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ V1       V2       V3      
     │ Float64  Float64  Float64 
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │     3.0    NaN      NaN
   2 │   NaN        4.0    NaN
   3 │     1.0    NaN      NaN
   4 │   NaN      NaN        7.0
   5 │   NaN      NaN      NaN
```

I would like to combine them all to one column and rename that column to for example "v_comb" This is the desired output:

```
5×1 DataFrame
 Row │ V_comb  
     │ Float64 
─────┼─────────
   1 │     3.0
   2 │     4.0
   3 │     1.0
   4 │     7.0
   5 │   NaN
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to combine multiple columns with NaN to one column in Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the columns and replace the values which are nan.

```
let
  res = df[:,1]
  i = findall(isnan.(res))
  for j in 2:ncol(df)
    res[i] .= df[i,j]
    i = i[isnan.(res[i])]
    length(i) == 0 && break
  end
  DataFrame(V_comb = res)
end
#5×1 DataFrame
# Row │ V_comb  
#     │ Float64 
#─────┼─────────
#   1 │     3.0
#   2 │     4.0
#   3 │     1.0
#   4 │     7.0
#   5 │   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessarily complicated, but gets it done in one line.

```
reduce.((a, b) -> isnan(a) ? b : a, eachrow(df))
```

Output

```
5-element Vector{Float64}:
   3.0
   4.0
   1.0
   7.0
 NaN
```

`(a, b) -> isnan(a) ? b : a` returns the element that is not `NaN` from the pair of numbers `a, b`.

`reduce` with this function, applied on an array returns *the* element that is not `NaN` (breaks if there are more than one element that is not `NaN`.

`reduce.(f, eachrow(df))` applies it to each row of `df`.